# Physics.Linecast() doesn't detect ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I have a camera that is following the player (third person view).

i have this code to check if the camera hits something:

```
    if (Physics.Linecast(transform.position, cameraMain.transform.position, layerMask))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }
```

but it doesn't detect my ground, which is a 3D Cube.

The cube has a box collider on it with "Is Trigger" unchecked.

With every other object the script works perfect!

Edit: layerMask is only ignoring layer #10, but the cube has layer #1

Edit2: here is the code for the layerMask setup:

```
int layerMask = 1 << 10;
layerMask = ~layerMask;
```

Comment: what are you doing differently between this and your other objects? only thing I can think is that the layermask is set up wrong. try inverting it, or removing and see if you still are not getting results

Comment: layers are okay, and the way i control the layers in the code is this: 
int layerMask = 1 << 10;
layerMask = ~layerMask;

Comment: Does your camera have raycasts component enabled?

Comment: @Lotan what do you mean with raycast component? I don't know about that. But at least it works with everything, except the cube (ground)

Comment: @AlpakaJoe I mean that if your camera don't have "Physics Raycaster" component it won't work. But if is working with everything else...your ground have a collider? Did you try replacing Linecast with Raycast to see if it detects the ground?

Comment: @Lotan i found the problem .. very stupid mistake, the players pivot point was a little bit in the ground, so the ground didn't get detected.. thanks for your help anyway!